# I subsequently realised that I asked a duplicate question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

That's because I stumbled upon the original question; at the time my question was not shown to be under suspicion or anything.

What's the right thing to do in that case?

It happened recently: I asked a question and the only comment was to clarify what I was asking. Later that day that I noticed that it was a duplicate, so I apologised for it in a comment, providing a link to the question that was already answered comprehensively. (It was about 24 hours later that my question was flagged as duplicate.)

Comment: Just delete the question if both are same

Comment: @OptimusPrime Considering that at the time people had already seen it it and probably want to know the answer as well, I expect a more helpful course of action would be to provide the link, but that may be just my opinion.

Comment: @OptimusPrime - **no, don't delete it**. Leaving it as a duplicate makes the post act as a signpost, using different keywords to point people to the answer they need. **Deleting duplicates is a bad idea.**

Comment: @Mithrandir I tend to disagree with that. If the Q have a negative score too, then it will be roombaed. Filling duplicate stuff to help future visitors is not a good idea

Comment: @OptimusPrime - [I don't think dupes are roomba'd](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169665/rick-riordan-books). That's a link to a question asked over 30 days ago, no answers, negative score, closed as a duplicate, not deleted.

Comment: Correction: yes, they are roomba'd, sorry @OptimusPrime.

Comment: What are dupes and what does it mean that they are roomba'd?

Comment: @Heimdall dupes are duplicates, roomba'd means cleaned up.

Comment: @Heimdall roomba is an automatic process to clean up some questions. read more [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you don't have enough reputation to cast a close vote - or even  any reputation -  you can close it yourself as a duplicate without anybody else needing to get involved.

If you have 250 reputation, you can cast close votes on your own question. So you can vote to close your own question as a duplicate, and then click the 'that solved my problem' button to close the question by Community♦ as a duplicate.

If you have less than 250 reputation, you can flag your own question for closure as a duplicate:

[image]

And then you can again click the *That solved my problem!* box.

[image]

Comment: @ShadowWizard - users can always flag their own posts, even with 1 rep. I have a sock, I tested it.

Comment: Huh, thanks. But are you sure it's not just "Other", and 1 rep user gets all possible flags?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - yup, sure. I just looked now with my sock's eyes. Gets the 'other', 'duplicate', and 'closure' flags available, just like me on MusicFans.SE.

Comment: Thanks. It probably happened because I posted the question on my phone and the mobile page doesn't show related questions as you type...

Comment: @Heimdall - don't forget that you can accept this answer by pressing the gray checkmark under the vote buttons ;)

Comment: Fishing for more reputation? ;-) Actually I meant to do it but forgot.

Comment: @Heimdall - nah, just I know what people forget (I usually do) and so since I appreciate when people poke me, I poke others too :P